# use javascript to implement slideshow and create a new page when user click the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, frontend

I am new to javeScript and I am creating a website with slideshow feature. I want "when the user click the forward or backward button, the slideshow URL will change to "slideshow/img#1, slideshow/img#2, etc", but it is still a single page application." Can anyone give some idea? Thank you.

Note: This is not a homework or any academic work, but just my personal project.

Answer (score 0):

There is a slider in angularjs which can be used by injecting [ui.bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

**Working plunker:** https://plnkr.co/edit/aTl515SYqSawOk6f97RM?p=preview

**script.js**

```
  angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope){
      $scope.myInterval = 3000;
      $scope.slides = [
        {
          image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'
        },
        {
          image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food'
        },
        {
          image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports'
        },
        {
          image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people'
        }
      ];
    }
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" id="slides_control">
    <div>
      <carousel interval="myInterval">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
          <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
          </div>
        </slide>
      </carousel>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. But I want that every time I click the arrow, it will create a new page for a new image but the same logic. I found this website slideshow has this feature http://www.ocweekly.com/slideshow/first-look-the-country-club-in-costa-mesa-8586975.